# Magento2 attribute issue

Tags: magento, magento2

We have install magento2 EE. We are facing issue on attribute save. attribute already created and now when i tried to save getting below error.

"The value of Admin must be unique."

Can anyone please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
Seems your attribute have multiple options with same values.

If you want to use multiple options with same values then 
Set unique value to "No" (Advanced Attribute Properties->Unique Value) 

If you dont want multiple values then delete duplicate values 
from db through script or do it manually.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB8lX.png)